# How to make a request and build a URL with array items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The commented out code works but only for a single team, I'm trying to iterate over all of the teamIDs in order to get their roster players IDs and store them within the array playerList.

The part I'm not sure how to deal with is actually making the request to the link and iterating over each object within the teamID array and using those values in the link im requesting from.

```
var teamID = [];
var playerList = [];

d3.json('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams', function(data) {
    for (i=0; i < 31; i++) {
        teamID.push(data.teams[i].id);
  }
});

console.log(teamID);

// d3.json('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/1/?expand=team.roster', function(data) {
//   for (k=teamID[0]; k < teamID.length, k++) {
//
//     for (i=0; i < data.teams[0].roster.roster.length; i++) {
//       playerList.push(data.teams[0].roster.roster[i].person.id);
//
//     }}
// });

//console.log(playerList);

var item;

for (i=0; i < teamID.length; i++) {
  for (item in teamID[i]) {
    d3.json('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/'+item+'/?expand=team.roster', function(data) {
      for (k=0; k < data.teams[i].roster.roster.length; k++) {
        playerList.push(data.teams[i].roster.roster[k].person.id);
      }
    })
  }
};

console.log(playerList);
```

Comment: Put your processing part in the callback of the HTTP response

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the teamID array **before** getting an answer from your AJAX request,  You should process your teamID array after you get the answer, i.e in the **callback** of the d3.json :

```
var teamID = [];
var playerList = [];

d3.json('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams', function(data) {
    // this function is the callback of your d3.json, it will be executed 
    // after you get an answer from your ajax call
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        teamID.push(data.teams[i].id);
    }

    console.log(teamID);

    for (i = 0; i < teamID.length; i++) {
        for (item in teamID[i]) {
            d3.json('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/' + item + '/?expand=team.roster', function(data) {
                for (k = 0; k < data.teams[i].roster.roster.length; k++) {
                    playerList.push(data.teams[i].roster.roster[k].person.id);
                }
                console.log(playerList);
            })
        }
    };


});
```

Comment: You might want to actually put your players in a 2 dimensions array : playerList[teamID][]

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding but you mean I should put the for (item in teamID[i]) loop after the call back from the d3.json line? The problem is there won't be a callback because item won't be defined?